# Volley: WooCommerce HTTPS REST API HTTPS Authentications return error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: android, wordpress, rest, authentication, android-volley

I am trying to use volley to fetch my product list on my WordPress store using [Rest API HTTP basic Auth](https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#authentication-over-https) but it keeps returning error 401 unauthorized.

This is my code:

```
private void getProducts() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getProducts called");
        String url = "https://www.mystoreurl.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products";
        mJsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called with " + response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse called for getProducts");
                NetworkResponse errorResponse = error.networkResponse;
                if (errorResponse != null && errorResponse.data != null) {
                    String statusCode = String.valueOf(errorResponse.statusCode);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status code is " + statusCode);
                    String fullMessage = new String(errorResponse.data);
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error message is " + fullMessage);
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                String key = getString(R.string.store_consumer_Key);
                String secret = getString(R.string.store_consumer_secret);
                headers.put("consumer_key", key);
                headers.put("consumer_secret", secret);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(mJsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

However, if I put the consumer key and secret as parameters in the url like this:

```
private void getProducts() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getProducts called");
        String key = getString(R.string.store_consumer_Key);
        String secret = getString(R.string.store_consumer_secret);

        String url = "https://www.mystoreurl.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products?consumer_key=" + key + "&consumer_secret=" + secret;
        mJsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called with " + response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse called for getProducts");
                NetworkResponse errorResponse = error.networkResponse;
                if (errorResponse != null && errorResponse.data != null) {
                    String statusCode = String.valueOf(errorResponse.statusCode);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status code is " + statusCode);
                    String fullMessage = new String(errorResponse.data);
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error message is " + fullMessage);
                }
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(mJsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

It works, but I am concerned about security. Please is this secure? If not, then how can I authenticate through the headers?

Comment: Are **consumer_key** and **consumer_secret** both belonging to HTTP headers?? I think it should be as parameter. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @i-Droid, I really don't know. But security-wise, is there any way to encode the consumer key and secret?

Comment: Yes you can encode it using **form-urlencoded**.